# Multiple 'for' loop in list in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, arraylist, nested-loops

Here is the code I've tried :

```
booksa = [book[i] for book in books for k in range(len(lista)) for i in lista[k][0] ]
booksb = [book[j] for book in books for e in range(len(lista)) for j in lista[e][1] ]
```

Hi, I am not that familiar with loops in a list - list comprehension. I have a list named `'books'`, and a list named `'lista'`. I want to find the second element of every tuple in `books` with `lista` as index and store the corresponding pairs in lists `booksa` and `booksb`.

```
books = [(17,5), (3,55), (5,12), (14,9), (16,1), (9,5), (5,6), (18,13), (19,7), (1,20), (4,12), (11,1), (8,6), (8,18), (3,4), (13,7), (17,22), (20,7)]
lista = [[(0,9), (3,10), (6,15)]]
```

For example, for `(0,9)` in `lista`, we look back at `books` and find `17`(0 means the first tuple) in `(17,5)` and then put `17` in `booksa`, and `7`(9 means the eighth tuple) in `(9,5)` to put in `booksb`.

How can I do this in list with some 'for' loops?

Comment: "9 means the eighth tuple" - This is not clear. In that case, 0 means which tuple? Do 0 and 1 represent the same tuple?

Answer (score 2):

The logic applied is like below:

- Pick the first item in the `lista` tuple element and use that to index into `books` list and get the first item of tuple present there to add to `booksa`
- Pick the second item in the `lista` tuple element and use that to index into `books` list and get the second item of tuple present there to add to `booksb`

Check the below code:

```
books = [(17,5), (3,55), (5,12), (14,9), (16,1), (9,5), (5,6), (18,13), (19,7), (1,20), (4,12), (11,1), (8,6), (8,18), (3,4), (13,7), (17,22), (20,7)]
lista = [[(0,9), (3,10), (6,15)]]

booksa = []
booksb = []
for x in lista:
   for y in x:
       booksa.append(books[y[0]][0])
       booksb.append(books[y[1]][1])

print ("booksa = %s" %(booksa))
print ("booksb = %s" %(booksb))
```

Output:

```
booksa = [17, 14, 5]
booksb = [20, 12, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

using list comprehension

```
books = [(17,5), (3,55), (5,12), (14,9), (16,1), (9,5), (5,6), (18,13), (19,7), (1,20), (4,12), (11,1), (8,6), (8,18), (3,4), (13,7), (17,22), (20,7)]
lista = [[(0,9), (3,10), (6,15)]]

booksa = [books[k[0]][0] for j in lista for k in j]
booksb = [books[k[1]][1] for j in lista for k in j]

"""
# output 
booksa = [17, 14, 5]
booksb = [20, 12, 7]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple unpacking to improve readability:

```
booksa = [books[i][0] for i, _ in lista[0]]
# [17, 14, 5]

booksb = [books[j][1] for _, j in lista[0]]
# [20, 12, 7]
```

If you have multiple sublists in `lista` use `itertools.chain(lista)` instead of `lista[0]`.